line of program before sleep not run
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5 import QtGui
import sys
import time


class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()

        self.setGeometry(0, 0, 400, 300)
        self.label = QLabel("Hello", self)
        self.label.move(100, 100)
        self.label.setStyleSheet("border: 1px solid black;")
        self.show()
        time.sleep(2)
        self.close()



App = QApplication(sys.argv)

window = Window()

sys.exit(App.exec())

When I run program the window opens but widgets not show and after 2s it closes.
What I expected was the window opens and widgets show and after 2s it closes.

You need to tag the specific technology you are using.

QMainWindow.show relies on a background event loop that is handled by the qt's engine (which runs on the main thread). Once you call time.sleep, it blocks the main thread for 2s, preventing the event loop from executing, giving the appearance that the application has frozen. In order to achieve what you want without freezing the app, you could try to use QTimer, scheduling QMainWindow.close to be called after 2s using QTimer.singleShot.

That "line" is actually running, otherwise you wouldn't see a window at all. As Carl explained above, you're blocking the event loop, preventing anything (including drawing the contents) in the meantime, which is why you should never use blocking functions or long for/while loops in the main thread (nor try to access UI elements from external threads, so don't even think about calling close() from another thread). Remove that sleep and change the following line to QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(2000, self.close). Then do some research about event loops and their usage in UI toolkits.
